# Usage of @Bean annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

Suppose I have the following *Spring* context configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public A a() {
        return new A(b());
    }

    public B b() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Should one annotate `b()` with `@Bean` if the only place where `B` instance needed is within `a()` for `A` instance construction?

Comment: Your current setup doesn't make the `B` instance a Spring managed bean. So if you expect things like `@PostConstruct` etc. on that bean to work it will simply fail as spring doesn't manage it. Next are you sure that that is going to be the only instance of `B` you ever going to need or maybe you need it in multiple places, then what?

Comment: Why not just instantiate `B` inside `A` then? Or, you can make `B` a bean, and then declare a field inside `A` which is `@Autowired`.

Comment: @m-deinum I noticed [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#__kafkalistener_annotation) that, for example, method `consumerConfigs()` is marked as `@Bean`...Maybe it's supposed to be used also somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `B` is a plan Java class (no Spring annotations) then no, You can use current configuration. As this is a private member of `A` class.

But if you have methods that need to be managed by spring (inside `B` class), like @PostConstruct or @PreDestroy, than you should make a Bean out of `B` class:

```
@Bean
public A a(B b) {
    return new A(b);
}
@Bean
public B b() {
    return new B();
}
```

Such cases are:

- resource to be closed on shutdown/close
- executors to be closed on shutdown
- jdbc connections
- etc